# Running an OSRM server in background, use it, kill it

Tags: bash, osrm

For a given map, I want to automate the following procedure:

1. Start an OSRM server
2. Do some request
3. Kill the server

It is pretty easy to do by hand, but I am facing the issue of single-threading, as the OSRM server and the requests are simultaneous. The killing phase can then be done using ps aux and extracting the process ID.

I have the following bash script

```
   OSM=sherbrooke.osm.pbf
    OSM_NAME=`basename $OSM`
    OSRM=`echo $OSM_NAME | cut -d "." -f 1`".osrm"
    
    cleanUp(){
        echo Cleaning
        rm -f $OSM_NAME
        rm -f $OSRM*
    }
    
    startOSRMserver(){
        echo Creating OSRM file
        cp $OSM .
        docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/$OSM_NAME
        
        if test -f "$OSRM"
        then
            echo Creating OSRM server
            docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-partition /data/$OSRM
            docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-customize /data/$OSRM
            docker run -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/$OSRM
            echo RUNNING
        else
            echo "Error while creating OSRM file"
        fi
    }
    
    cleanUp
    startOSRMserver
```

Which works fine when launched in the command line. But as soon as I try to send it in the background using &, the OSRM server is not available anymore with the message

```
unable to setup input stream: unable to set IO streams as raw terminal: interrupted system call
```

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I found the following way to be the most efficient

Just using a simple screen command

```
screen -S screenName -d -m ./start_osrm.sh
```

screenName can then be used to identify and kill the process